# ViewChild from ngTemplateOutlet coming from parent component

Tags: angular, viewchild, ngtemplateoutlet

I have a child component which accept a `TemplateRef` as an `@Input` and displays it through `ngTemplateOutlet`. How can I use `@ViewChild`/`@ViewChildren` to retrieve components inside the template ?

If the template is declared in the same component that where it is used, `@ViewChild`/`@ViewChildren` are working but it makes the component very less dynamic.

I also tried using `@ContentChildren` but it makes no difference.

I created a stackblitz in order to reproduce. Here are some of the code:

###### child.component.html

```
<ng-container #fromParent [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
```

###### child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<unknown>;
  @ViewChildren(HelloComponent) hello = new QueryList<HelloComponent>();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Has hello', this.hello.length > 0);
  }
}
```

###### parent.component.html

```
<ng-template #tmp> <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello> </ng-template>
<app-child [template]="tmp"> </app-child>
```

The log in child component returns `false`.

Here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eopzyw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Thank you.

Comment: I might be completely incorrect for you context, but I guess you can make use of [Content-projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection), also, have a look at this question [angular: access ng-content nested component method from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54304745/1417185)

Comment: It's not shown in my example but in my context the template should be reusable (in my usecase I use a `ngTemplateContextOutlet`). So I don't think `Content-projection` would do the trick as `ng-content` can only be used once unlike `ng-template`. But maybe I'm missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3):

This is interesting, at first look, I too thought that it should be accessible, but did some debugging and found that:

The parent template is part of the parent component host view and hence the `ViewChildren` in child component will not be able to access it as it is not the part of child component host view.

Look at the below picture, app component has a host id 165 and the parent ng template gets associated with it.

[image]

So it appears that in the current design of `ViewChildren` it does not support querying the templates passed from a host view. May be opening a feature request will be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the analyze. I created a feature request at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43946. Let's see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @Ritesh Waghela discovered I found a way to get the views inside the template but is has some drawbacks.

---

So because only the parent knows the existence of those views, it's his work to get their references.

###### parent.component.ts

```
@ViewChildren(HelloComponent) public helloComponents = new QueryList<HelloComponent>();
```

The child will then get a reference to the parent thanks to `Injector`.

###### child.component.ts

```
private parent: ParentComponent;
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
   this.parent = injector.get<ParentComponent>(ParentComponent);
}
```

Because the `@ViewChildren` of the parent will take all the `HelloComponent`, in template or not, we need to differentiate them. For this I did not find any better solution than adding an attribute inside `HelloComponent`.

###### hello.component.ts

```
@Input() fromTemplate = false;
```

The parent component can distinguish `HelloComponent` inside template or not:

###### parent.component.html

```
<ng-template #tmp> 
  <hello name="inside template" fromTemplate="true"></hello>
</ng-template>

<hello name="outside template"></hello>
<app-child [template]="tmp"> </app-child>
```

The child component can now filter parent's views to get what it is searching for.

###### child.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const viewFromTemplate = this.parent.helloComponents.filter(
    (comp) => comp.fromTemplate
  );
}
```

This solution is working but it has a few drawbacks:

- The child must know the type of its parent;
- The parent must declare each view inside the template as being a "view from template";

The 1st drawback is not a huge issue in my case (it can be worked around because all of my components are contains inside a wrapper -> I take the reference to the known wrapper which can get a reference to the component it host).

But the 2nd drawback seems more of an issue to me. Does anyone knows if a view can know weither it is part of a `ng-template` or not ? I welcome any suggestion on this.

---

I created a `stackblitz` to demonstrate my solution: https://angular-qgwcdf.stackblitz.io.